# Linking not supported for whatsapp sandbox integrations

Tags: smooch

I'm trying to follow this [guide](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/whatsapp/#business-initiated) to start business initiated conversation in WhatsApp. I successfully created the user in the first step, but I cannot link it to the WhatsApp channel.

I'm calling API POST request:

```
https://api.smooch.io/v1.1/apps/{myAppID}/appusers/{myUserID}/channels
```

With body:

```
{
    "type":"whatsapp",
    "confirmation":{"type":"immediate"},
    "phoneNumber":"phoneNumberInInternationalFormat"
}
```

But result is:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "bad_request",
        "description": "Linking not supported for whatsapp sandbox integrations."
    }
}
```

So my question - is there any way to send a message using Sandbox number, or I need to register a number by requesting access process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linking API is disabled in Sandbox mode, but you can still send and receive messages from the phone number you used to set up the sandbox. Just send a message to the sandbox number and it will automatically create a user in your Smooch App. Then, you can use the API or business system integrations to reply just as you would with any other user.

See also the section on [user-initiated conversations](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/whatsapp/#user-initiated) in the WhatsApp guide

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you clarify how should I get the ID of the automatically created user?

Comment: You can see it in the Logs tab of the Smooch dashboard, or if you have a webhook configured for the `message:appUser` trigger, the payload you receive will include the user's ID

Comment: Thanks, I've already found out it! My mistake was that I was trying to send messages to my number which I've bound, instead of Smooch sandbox number.

Comment: Also maybe it is a wrong place to ask, but during the period my personal number have been bound to sandbox, I was not able to receive any calls or SMS. I also didn't found any warnings about such behaviour. Is that expected?

Comment: No it's not expected. The only thing setting up the sandbox does is store your number on Smooch's side, it doesn't affect any behaviour of your device at all